# Regex for Alphanumeric and ' ', '-', '_', and '.'?

Tags: regex

Hey can anyone whip up a regex that i could use to validate strings containing only alphanumeric characters along with ' ', '-', '_', and '.' ?

Thanks

Comment: How is it possible to know what a regex is and yet not know the answer to this question?

Comment: cause i read jeff's blog

Comment: Irony... capacitors... overloaded... barely... holding... on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9 _.-]+$/
```

or, where supported,

```
/^[\w .-]+$/
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/^[\w. -]*$/
```

The `\w` predefined character class includes alphanumeric characters and underscores, and is shorter to type than `a-zA-Z0-9_` Also, depending on whether you want to allow empty strings or not, you'll want to use either `*` or `+`.

Comment: Correct. But the vast majority do.

Comment: I've never come across one that doesn't support shorthand character classes. Example?

Comment: Uhm, POSIX and GNU BRE and ERE?

Comment: POSIX "Basic Regular Expressions"

Comment: Good to know, I don't get out much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 \-_.]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

@chaos or anyone else:
I am just curious, where isn't \w and \d stuff supported. I use them in Perl and Ruby. I had the idea that they are supported by every language.